# Is Facebook generating new webpage for every user accounts or they just using 1 webpage for every account?

Tags: facebook, web-services, facebook-graph-api, web, web-development-server

What actually happen if `NEW USER` creates an account in `Facebook`? does the Facebook generate a new `Web Page` for it? or They just have `1 Web Page` for all user account and all of them are accessing the page when they are online? I am new in web development and i want to know if how Facebook actually handling the process when the user created an account. I want to know if every user has they `own Web Page` `generated` by the `server side scrip.` and saved on the server and access it when they are online, or there is `only one web page` on the server and all of the user are accessing this page when they are online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact details of how the views are shown by Facebook i.e. which technologies they use, but they don't have a page for each user that is for sure.

If you want to verify that check the url. Is it loading a different html document for each request or each user? The url will change but it is not request for a particular document, it will specify a route which will be mapped to a request to the server and new data will be retrieved and put into appropriate place.

Take a look into Single Page Applications (SPA) and technologies like AngularJS or BackboneJS and similar libraries which enable us to creating such applications.If you are new to ajax learn about it because that is the core of this functionality. On server side any MVC framework with routing can be used to implement this behavior. NodeJS is one option.

So to answer your question. It has to be a single (or if not single very few) template(s) html which are used to render everything.

Comment: Ahhw. OK, Thank you so much! I thought they have one page for every user.